# use threading to fill list of object

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, list

I am using a list to fill Combo box control in windows form load. There are around 20,000+ records 
populating on it, and The list performs very slow in this case.

and i use threading to speed up the performs , but it not fill the list 
can you help me

this is the threading

```
Thread UpdateThread;
      ThreadStart UpdateThreadStart = new ThreadStart(FillCombBox);
      static MethodInvoker CallDataBindToDataGrid = new MethodInvoker(FilDiagtWithdatat);
```

and i put this in the load

```
UpdateThread = new Thread(UpdateThreadStart);
UpdateThread.Name = "Update Thread";
UpdateThread.IsBackground = true;
UpdateThread.Start();
```

and this is my 2 method

```
static void FillCombBox()
        {
            CBList = Items.GeItemsAll(1);

        }

static void FilItemtWithdatat()
        {
            if (CBList.Count!=0)
            {
                MyForm.CB_Item.DataSource = ItemList;
                MyForm.CB_Item.ValueMember = "ItemID";
                MyForm.CB_Item.DisplayMember = "ItemName";
                MyForm.CB_Item.SelectedIndex = -1;
            }

        }
```

myform : i but this line in the top `static ItemHome MyForm;`
CBList : is public list in the form

Comment: Which programming language is this? You might want to add the corresponding tag.

Comment: C# and connect to SQL

Comment: even if you do the work in a background thread, at some point you still are returning 20k records from a database.  how much time does that take on its own?

Comment: I seriously doubt that the list itself is the problem. A list of 20000 elements is elements is really nothing to speak of unless the records are huge.

Comment: Wouldnt be lazy evaluation better? Display only what you really need - i am sure you dont have combo box displaying 20k object at once. Not sure about combobox but as far as I remember - flow layout panel can look similar and supports it.

Comment: i am only need to speed up the form load and get the 20,000 rows , if there another way ????

Comment: @John Gardner it take 1 M

Comment: if it takes 1 minute, and the combo then has 20k records in it, you need some other control than a combobox!  if I wanted to get to the 18,884th item in the list, i'd have to scroll FOREVER! (and hope I never accidentally make the popup go away...)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with 3,000 records.  I found that turning  the autocompletemode in the combobox to none during the loop and then turn it back on after the loop is finished, made it just as fast as a direct query to the sql database.  Hope this helps.